# Real Analysis, Problem 1.4.17 Outer Measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> If $\mu^*$ is an outer measure on $X$ and $\{A_j\}_{1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of disjoint $\mu^*$-measurable sets, then $\mu^*\left(E\cap\left(\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}A_j\right)\right) = \sum_{1}^{\infty}\mu^*(E\cap A_j)$ for any $E\subset X$.

Attempted proof - From countable subadditivity, $$\mu^*\left(E\cap\left(\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}A_j\right)\right) = \mu^*\left(\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}E\cap A_j\right) \leq \sum_{1}^{\infty}\mu^*(E\cap A_j)$$
Let $B_n = \bigcup_{1}^{n}A_j$. For each $n\geq 2$ since $A_n$ is $\mu^*$-measurable we have \begin{align*}
\mu^*(E\cap B_n) &= \mu^*((E\cap B_n)\cap A_n) + \mu^*((E\cap B_n)\cap A_n^c)\\
&= \mu^*(E \cap A_n) + \mu^*(E\cap B_{n-1})\\
\end{align*}
(These 2 lines above me came from part of the proof in Carthedory's Theorem and I don't really understand it at all if someone would be so kind to explain that part to me.)

By induction, $\mu^*(E\cap B_n) = \sum_{1}^{n}\mu^*(E\cap A_j)$ for all $n\geq 1$. So then by monotonocity, $$\mu^*\left(E\cap\left(\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}A_j\right)\right) \geq \mu(E\cap B_n) = \sum_{1}^{n}\mu^*(E\cap A_j)$$ for all $n\geq 1$. Thus as $n\rightarrow \infty$ we have the result.

Comment: The countable subadditivity gives you a $\leqslant$ in the last relation. You need to show $\geqslant$ to complete the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use $\mu^*$ measurability and induction to conclude that the relation to be proved holds for finitely many $A_j$.

For convenience, let's denote the relation to be proved by $(*)$. Say we have $n$ of $A_j$. For $n = 1$, there is nothing to prove. In the case $n = 2$, if $A_1 \cup A_2 = X$, then $(*)$ is just a restatement of $\mu^*$ measurability. 
If $A_1 \cup A_2$ is smaller than $X$, split  $E \cap (A_1 \cup A_2)$ by $A_1$ and $A_1^c$, then since $A_1$ is $\mu^*$-measurable and $A_1 \cap A_2 = \varnothing$,
\begin{align*}
& \mu^*(E \cap (A_1 \cup A_2)) \\ 
= & \mu^*(E \cap (A_1 \cup A_2) \cap A_1) + \mu^*(E \cap (A_1 \cup A_2) \cap A_1^c) \\
= & \mu^*(E \cap A_1) + \mu^*(E \cap A_2).
\end{align*}

Assume $(*)$ holds for the case of $n - 1$ sets. By the case $n = 2$, together with the induction hypothesis, 
$$\mu^*(E \cap (\cup_{j = 1}^n A_j)) = \mu^*(E \cap (\cup_{j = 1}^{n - 1}A_j)) + \mu^*(E \cap A_n) = \sum_{j = 1}^n \mu^*(E \cap A_j).$$

For the infinite case use monotonicity: for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$\mu^*(E \cap (\cup_{j = 1}^\infty A_j)) \geq \mu^*(E \cap (\cup_{j = 1}^n A_j)) = \sum_{j = 1}^n \mu^*(E \cap A_j).$$
Let $n \to \infty$, the result follows.

Comment: Can you give me your reasoning for your first point? Why must we show the relation to be proved holds for finitely many $A_j$?

Comment: OK. I will add more details.

Comment: Also just to clairfy your second point which seems obvious to me say we have a set $A = \bigcup_{1}^{\infty} E\cap A_j$ and $B = \bigcup_{1}^{n} E\cap A_j$ then can we say that $B\subset A$ then by monotonicty $\mu(B)\leq \mu(A)$? Second questions is $B\leq A$?

Comment: @Wolfy Yes, as by definition, outer measure is monotone.

Comment: I don't really follow your first part at all is that necessary to have for the proof to be complete? Perhaps I do not understand what the question is asking us to do. In my proof my first statement is correct. Now from what I can tell all I have to do is show the opposite relation and then I have my result. So, using the last part of your answer it appears that I would be done. If what I am saying is not correct please let me know

Comment: The last equality rests on the finite-additivity, otherwise how can I claim the equality?

Comment: Can you explain how it rests on finite-additivity? By last equality are you stating the second to last line of your answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39960/discussion-between-solitary-and-wolfy).

Comment: Hey can you see my edited answer. I believe I am fine now but if you could, can you explain to me the () I have about the Carthedory's theorem. It is more of a set theory question that I don't understand

Comment: What I seem to have a problem with is parts of set theory just as in your content I am confused about the intersection and union parts